# Is this recursive GCD function correct?

Tags: c, recursion

Everything compiles and runs perfectly for my program. I had to write a recursive GCD function. I used two functions however, gcdRecursive and gcd. Can I condense this code into a single function so I do not need the gcd function within my code below? Or is my code correct as it is and the two functions are both needed.

```
void gcdRecursive(int *x, int *y, int i){
  if (i >= 1) {
    if (*x % i == 0 && *y % i == 0) {
        printf("The GCD of %d and %d is %d", *x, *y, i); 
    } 
    else {
        gcdRecursive(x, y, i - 1);
    }
  }
}
void gcd(int *x, int *y){
  getValuesForGCD(x, y);
  gcdRecursive(x, y, *x);
}
```

Comment: You `gcd` function is a wrapper dedicated to interacting with the input environment: all the work happens in `gcdRecursive`. It is already unneeded for computing greatest common divisors. Programs generally need some kind of IO arrangements to be useful, of course, but that is separate of whatever computation you are doing.

Comment: Please stop doing spam edits just to bump your question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is correct but it is by far sub-optimal.

EDIT: try to use this:

```
if (x > y) 
  gcd(x,y) = gcd(y, x);
if (y % x == 0)
  gcd(x, y) = x;
else 
  gcd(x, y) = gcd(x, y%x)
```

Comment: You can compute gcd recursively in way less operations(computational-wise)

Comment: See my edit for an alternative solution

Comment: That will not work. It needs a third parameter as shown in my code above. Your code is sufficient but not workable code for my current code...

Comment: @QweRty You might try looking up the subject in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm) before refusing advice…

Answer (score 1):

A more compact form could be

```
int getGcd(int num1, int num2)
{
    int remainder;

    if(num2 != 0)
        remainder = (num1 % num2);
    return ((num2 == 0) ? num1: getGcd(num2, remainder));
}
```