# stuck in GCD of 2 numbers in C using recursion

Tags: c

I am getting segmentation fault with the following program. I am trying to find out the GCD using recursive function. The code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    int temp, g, c;
    if(a>b)
    {
        c=a;
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }

    //printf("The values of a and b are: %d %d",a,b);
    temp = a % b;

    if(temp != 0)
    {
        g = gcd(b, temp);
        return(g);
    }

    if(temp == 0)
        g= b;

    return g;
}

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter two numbers: \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    printf("The GCD of two numbers you entered are: %d\n", gcd(a,b));
}
```

The problem that I found out is in swapping variables. If I am removing it then the code is working fine. Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong? I am trying to implement it using `Euclidean algorithm`. So no other method can be implemented.

Comment: It's just showing me segmentation fault

Comment: Stackoverflow then?  Run it in a debugger.

Comment: it's infinitely printing the printf statement which I have done // in my code above

Comment: Your problem is that the recursion never terminates. gcd() is calling itself again and again, never stopping. This results in all stack memory getting exhausted due to the recursion never stopping. This condition is called a "stack overflow." The best way to understand the problem is by running the program in a debugger and stepping through the code line by line, observing the values of the variables which should show you why the recursion never terminates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this recursive GCD function correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898583/is-this-recursive-gcd-function-correct)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(a>b)
{
    c=a;
    a=b;
    b=c;
}

temp = a % b;
```

The problem is here. First, you're making sure that `b > a`. Now, if b is greater than a, it's not difficult to prove that `a % b == a`. For instance, 2 % 5 = 2.

Just replace the last line with

```
temp = b % a;
```

or, even better, reverse the condition for swapping :

```
if(a < b)
```

Comment: What doesn't work, exactly? What solution(s) have your tried from the 2 I suggested?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of swapping the variables at the GCD function,Find the max number and send it as **a** and min number as **b** in the main function itself.

```
    int GCD(int a, int b)
    {
        if (b == 0)
            return a;
        else
            return GCD(b, a % b);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be

```
if (a < b)
```

Because doing

```
// Pre-condition: a >= b
temp = a % b;
// Post-condition: temp < b or temp == 0.
```

then the call `gcd(b, temp)`

has: `temp < b, b <= min(original a, original b)`

And so gcd terminates (variant `a + b` getting smaller on every call).

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no need for the if (a > b) test, just remove it. If a >= b, the code works just as you want; if not, the first recursive call just do the swap.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to check for each step which is greater (a or b).

Use following function to calculate gcd of two numbers.

```
int gcd(int a ,int b){
    if(a % b == 0)
        return b;
    return gcd(b,a%b);
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score -1):

Why to complicate things that much? Use this:

```
int findgcd(int x,int y){
     while(x!=y){
          if(x>y)
              return findgcd(x-y,y);
          else
             return findgcd(x,y-x);
     }
     return x;
}
```

Comment: Using `-` instead of `% `makes this slow!